# Escape sequence with "\" symbol

Tags: c#

i have one string, and i assign the value like,

```
string str="admin" + @"\" + "user";
```

The output of the "str" value comes as

> "admin`\\`user"

. But i need "str" value as

> "admin`\`user"

.
That means i need single `"\"` symbol instead of `"\\"` within the string values. How can i get this?

Comment: where do you get the output from?

Answer (score 11):

> The output of the "str" value comes as "admin\\user"

No, it really doesn't. The string itself will just have a single backslash.

**If you look at it in the debugger** you will see the escaping, but that doesn't mean it's part of the string. It's just the debugger representation. Print it to the console, or log etc to see the real value.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure your string is actually fine.

I am guessing you are looking at the value in the debugger and seeing `\\`. This is because the *debugger* is escaping a single `\` to `\\` to make it clear to you that this is a slash and not a control code.

For example, the debugger shows a tab as `\t`, so in order to show you a slash followed by the letter `t` it escapes it to `\\t`.

If you write this string out to console/log/file, you'll see it is as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
String str = @"admin\user"
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for reply,,, The "admin" & "user" is comes from Database, that means string str1="admin"; and string str2="user" means,, i need the output like => string str= str1 + @"\" + str2;

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where your problem lies... Looks fine to me. - View stuff as the end user, and not in the debugger as Rob suggests.

[image]