# reading a CSV issue

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to read a csv

following is the sample.

```
"0734306547          ","9780734306548       ","Jane Eyre Pink PP                       ","Bronte Charlotte                        ","FRONT LIST",20/03/2013 0:00:00,0,"PAPERBACK","Y","Pen"
```

Here is the code i am using read CSV

```
public void readCSV()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\abc\21-08-2013\PNZdatafeed.csv"),Encoding.ASCII);
            List<string> ISBN = new List<String>();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split(',');
                    if (values[9] == "Pen")
                    {
                        ISBN.Add(values[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(ISBN.Count().ToString());

        }
```

I am not able to compare it values `if (values[9] == "Pen")` because when i debug the code it says `values[9]` value is `\"Pen\""`

How do i get rid of the special characters.?

Comment: String.Replace("\"", "") is my first thought

Comment: This is the debugger attempting to be helpful. The value is actually "Pen", but the debugger is showing it as an escaped string. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9922604/1822164

Comment: You should use a CSV-reading library to read it - CSV may look like a trivial format, but it's not, as you're discovering.  Think about what happens when one of the values contains a quote, for instance.

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: That's slightly misleading.  The value does have quotes, but not backslashes.  It's five characters, `"` `P` `e` `n` `"`

Comment: @RichieHindle I agree, but this is a "I don't know how to use the debugger" issue.

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: It's at least partly a "how do I get rid of these quote characters?" issue.

Comment: @RichieHindle I know, that is what I point out when I say *The value is actually **"Pen"*** (emphasis mine).

Comment: Keep in mind that splitting by comma will also create a problem when you have commas in the value.  i.e: "A", "b", "a, b" should be 3 values, since you are using " as a text qualifier

Comment: For reading CSV with quoting and escaping, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/769713/4525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're splitting the line every time you find `,` and leaving the data like that.  For example, if this is the line you're reading in:

```
 "A","B","C"
```

and you split it at commas, you'll get `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"` as your data.  According to your description, you don't want quotes around the data.

To throw away quotes around a string:

1. Check if the leftmost character is `"`.
2. If so, check if the rightmost character is `"`.
3. If so, remove the leftmost and rightmost characters.

In pseudocode:

```
 if (data.left(1) == "\"" && data.right(1) == "\"") {
      data = data.trimleft(1).trimright(1)
 }
```

At this point you might have a few questions (I'm not sure how much experience you have).  If any of these apply to you, feel free to ask them, and I'll explain further.

1. What does `"\""` mean?
2. How do I extract the leftmost/rightmost character of a string?
3. How do I extract the middle of a string?