# Put Quote Mark in between 2 string objects

Tags: c#, string

I have looked and looked and look for a way to put a " in between 2 string objects.
I know you can use "\"" to get a quote or even @"""" for the same result.

```
string quote = "\"";
string cheatName = "UnlockTankLine(" + nationNum.ToString() + "," + quote + 
                                   nationTankName[1] + quote  + ")";

m_cheater.ActivateCheat(cheatName);
```

I need a result of "UnlockTankLine(int, "name")"... but when i do the above i get something like
"UnlockTankLine(int, \"name\")" and this isn't working with a cmd line for our game.

NOW if i am dumb and \"name\" is the same thing as "name" and the problem might be somewhere else. The only reason why I think i am not being dumb is if i use a different cheat cmd that doesn't take a string it works fine. Example UnlockWholeTankLine(int) works

Comment: If you don't want to use @, I think you can use unicode values like \u00xx

Comment: Don't use `<code>`. Just indent your code by 4 characters or more. You can do this by selecting it and pressing Control-K.

Comment: Are you seeing \"name\" in the debugger? In the debugger you will see the \" instead of " because the debugger needs to escape the string as well. If you write it to the console or use the Text Visualizer you will see the \ is not present.

Comment: I'm getting: `UnlockTankLine(1,"NAME")` with the above code as is. Write to `Console` or `TextBox` and see what the output is. What @CraigW. said. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Escape sequence with "\" symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922578/c-sharp-escape-sequence-with-symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try
to use format

```
 string cheatName = string.Format("UnlockTankLine({0},\"{1}\")",
                                  nationNum.ToString(), nationTankName[1])
```

Comment: `ToString` is obsolete when using `String.Format`. Using `String.Format` is an improvement but won't fix anything since his code works. He tapped into the debugger display escaping trap.